# Query results half right after joining two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

The following query resulted in correct results only for the inner query (post_engagement, website purchases) while all other numbers were incorrectly increased manyfold.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Schema of the two tables:

Favorite_ads (id, campaign_id, campaign_name, objective, impressions, spend)

Actions (id, ads_id, action_type, value)

```
SELECT
  f.campaign_id,
  f.campaign_name,
  f.objective,
  SUM(f.impressions) AS Impressions,
  SUM(f.spend) AS Spend,
  SUM(a.post_engagement) AS "Post Engagement",
  SUM(a.website_purchases) AS "Website Purchases"
FROM
favorite_ads f
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT
          ads_id,
          CASE WHEN action_type = 'post_engagement' THEN SUM(value) END AS 
post_engagement,
      CASE WHEN action_type = 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase' THEN SUM(value) END AS website_purchases
 FROM Actions a
 GROUP BY ads_id, action_type
) a ON f.id = a.ads_id
WHERE date_trunc('month',f.date_start) = '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND 
date_trunc('month',f.date_stop) = '2018-04-01 00:00:00' --only get campaigns 
that ran in April, 2018
GROUP BY f.campaign_id, campaign_name, objective
Order by campaign_id
```

Comment: At a glance, I wonder if in the subquery you should SUM the CASE's, instead of CASE the SUM's. While only grouping on ads_id.

Comment: But i wonder if inner group by is at all needed. Why not simply join this two tables and sum on that cases?

Comment: Please post `CREATE` statements for your tables, focusing on what are the primary keys, secondary keys (unique constraints) and references between those two tables (foreign keys). Some sample data, and expected results would also help.

Comment: On a side note, if the campaign duration was over a month (e.g. started in March and ended in may), don't you want it to be counted in the query? Also using filtering conditions on truncated column values will give you a very poor performance, if the table has lots of data. Rather use something like `f.date_start >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND f.date_start < '2018-05-01 00:00:00'`, which is effectively the same, but allows use of indexes.

Comment: Run the sub-query stand-alone. I assume it doesn't return what you expect it to do.

Comment: @jarlh: He actually wrote (first sentence) that he did run it and it did return correct data.

Comment: ads_id from the Actions table = id from the Favorite_ads table.

Comment: @ LukStorms, you're a genius!  After SUM the CASE instead of CASE the SUM and grouping by ads_id only, I got all correct results.  Thank you!  How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @Hilarion, still it ended up as a sub-query issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the actual table structure, constraints, dependencies and data, it's hard to tell, what the issue may be.

You already have some leads in the comments, which you should consider first.

For example you wrote, that this sub-query returns correct results:

```
SELECT ads_id,
       CASE
         WHEN action_type = 'post_engagement'
         THEN SUM(value)
       END AS post_engagement,
       CASE
         WHEN action_type = 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase'
         THEN SUM(value)
       END AS website_purchases
  FROM Actions a
 GROUP BY ads_id, action_type
```

Is this one also giving correct results:

```
SELECT ads_id,
       SUM(
         CASE
           WHEN action_type = 'post_engagement'
           THEN value
         END
       ) AS post_engagement,
       SUM(
         CASE
           WHEN action_type = 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase'
           THEN value
         END
       ) AS website_purchases
  FROM Actions
 GROUP BY ads_id
```

If so, then try replacing your sub-query with that one.

If you still have a problem, then I'd investigate if your join condition is correct, as it would seem, that for a campaign (`campaign_id`) you could probably have multiple entries with the same `id`, which will multiply the sub-query results - that depends on what is actually the primary key (or unique constraint) in the `favorite_ads`.

Comment: Thank you, Hilarion!  After revising the subquery as below per LukStorms suggestions, it worked!       SELECT
          ads_id,
          SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'post_engagement' THEN value END) AS post_engagement,
          SUM(CASE WHEN action_type = 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase' THEN value END) AS website_purchases,
     FROM Actions a
     GROUP BY ads_id          (Your second query seems similar.)